# AWS S3: SignatureDoesNotMatch when trying to get a signed URL to do browser upload

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file from my browser to S3 (Base64 format) but seems I have to first get a signed URL, but I never get a correct response trying to get this signed URL. Here is what I did:

```
...
const aws = require('aws-sdk')

MyController.get('/s3_sign', (req, res) => {

  let s3 = new aws.S3();
  aws.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "AKIAIWUTWWWBZM3IZNJAQ",
    secretAccessKey: "My_Secret_Key_Without_Any_Special_Characther"
  });

  let params = {
    Bucket: 'my-bucket-name',
    Key: 'file.jpg',
    Expires: 300
  };

  const url = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function(err, data){
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error uploading data: ", err);
      res.json({success: false})
    } else {
      console.log("URL: ", data);
      res.json({success: true, data: data})
    }
  });

})
```

I'm testing locally, when I hit this URL I get this response:

```
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
</Message>
<AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAIWUTWWWBZM3IZNJAQ</AWSAccessKeyId>
<StringToSign>
GET 1505923677 /my-bucket-name/button.png
</StringToSign>
<SignatureProvided>J41L/yY6SipfRcQa6yEjlrWahY8=</SignatureProvided>
<StringToSignBytes>
47 45 54 0a 0a 0a 31 35 30 35 39 32 33 36 37 37 0a 2f 63 6f 6e 70 61 73 73 2d 64 65 76 2f 63 6f 6e 70 61 73 73 2d 63 74 61 2d 62 6c 75 65 2d 31 78 2e 70 6e 67
</StringToSignBytes>
<RequestId>62398629E214AC9D</RequestId>
<HostId>
ZD9X7KkvhtKA5PBjfQXGo+IhHRSa0vVnWyEhdepB2O8h50OEP5iEsCHpV/UY27QqPFEgHf0kLu0=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

I've checked and my credentials are correct, without any spaces, any special characters. But I don't know why I never get it working.

I'm not sure if it's related because I even can't get the signed URL (before the upload) but my CORS settings is as follow:

```
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Content-Type</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>x-amz-acl</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>origin</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I look forward for some ideas on how to overcome this issue.

Comment: Are you invoking a PUT with data to the pre-signed URL? Wonder why the diagnostics show GET /my-bucket-name/button.png when your PUT is for /my-bucket-name/file.jpg. PS you should never include access keys and secret keys in the source of a web page.

Comment: The error is indicating that your access key & secret are wrong. You keep mentioning "secret without special characters". Your secret should be exactly as it's given to you. Don't remove any special characters. As a test, you should be able to do a `s3:ListBuckets` with your access key to verify it's working OK.

Comment: When you instantiate the S3 client, are you specifying a region that corresponds to where the bucket is located? Some regions mandate a particular signing algorithm that requires a region to be specified

Comment: @MattHouser sorry by confusion, what I mean is that the key and secret are ok, I haven't change anything. I can even list my objects with aws-sdk. The problem probably is something else.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to perform GET operation on a PUT url. If you want to get a signed url for GET method,

```
var params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key', Expires: 60};
var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
console.log('The URL is', url); // expires in 60 seconds
```

Detailed documentation at,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property

Comment: I'm trying to perform an upload from browser, the code above is in API and was created just to get this signed URL, as I can see it's correct because as I want to upload it I have to call `putObject` instead of `getObject`. Right? But I don't know why I'm receiving GET in my response.